How do i detect a tag on a post in forums channel in discord.py?
I searched through the internet and I couldn't find the answer I am asking here.
I want to make it so when a new post is created in a forum, the  bot checks its tags, and depending on which tags it has. It will add a link to the post to a list of links to be later posted via a slash command. How do I make a bot to detect the tags that are attached to the post?

The posts you see on a Forum Channel are actually Threads. You can get the tags of a thread like this:
your_forum_channel.threads[0].applied_tags

You can find more on the documentation:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=forumchannel#discord.Thread.applied_tags
Given what you want to do, this is probably what you want to do
@bot.event
async def on_thread_create(thread :discord.Thread):
    if thread.parent_id == your_forum_channel_id:
         tags = thread.applied_tags

